# Unable to open file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and I want to open a file with a wildcard. I've been struggling to get it to work. I know its very simple, please help.

```
Sub File_exists()
Dim orders As String
orders = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*ORDERS-Confirmed.xslx")
Workbooks.Open filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & orders

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really have `.xslx`... should be `.xlsx`.

Comment: If it is a newly created workbook without being saved, `ThisWorkbook.Path` returns blank.

Comment: What actually happens when you run that code?  You haven't given us any clues about what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open the most recent file that uses wildcard:

```
Sub File_exists()
    Dim orders As String
    orders = GetRecentFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*ORDERS-Confirmed.xslx")
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=orders
End Sub

Function GetRecentFile(ByVal FileNameWildCard As String) As String
    Dim sFiles As String
    sFiles = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & FileNameWildCard & """ /S /B /A:-D /O:-D").StdOut.ReadAll
    GetRecentFile = Split(sFiles, vbNewLine)(0)
End Function
```

This code lists files using command "dir" and orders by date